# Why is the connection refused in JATE2.0 Solr-7.2.1 in page home.html?

Tags: html, solr, connection-refused

I m using JATE2.0 Solr-7.2.1 for term scoring, ranking, filtering, indexing, storing and exporting but when i'm trying to click on the button Term Recognition in home.html i get this error

```
Connection refused. Terminology recognition service is not started. Please ask your administrator for help.
```

[file:///C:/Users/Sonja/jateSolrPluginDemo-master/JATE2-Web-Demo/web/home.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7NEg.png)

Here is my part for termRecogniser into the file solrconfig.xml

```
   <requestHandler name="/termRecogniser" class="uk.ac.shef.dcs.jate.solr.TermRecognitionRequestHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
 <str name="algorithm">TTF</str>
 <bool name="extraction">false</bool>
 <bool name="indexTerm">false</bool>
 <bool name="boosting">false</bool>
 <bool name="-c">true</bool>
 <str name="-o">../ttf-terms.json</str>
 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Can someone explain this problem! also when i try to put true for 
`<bool name="indexTerm">false</bool>`
i get an Error like **`this IndexReader is closed`** and it doesn't even generate home.html

Comment: If you're opening the HTML page directly in your browser, and that page assumes it can make requests to a backend service, my guess is that won't work - watch the developer console in your browser for any errors.

Comment: I execute first this cmd :

Comment: I execute first this cmd :`curl -X POST http://localhost:8983/solr/jateCore/termRecogniser` and after i open home.html but there is none **Top domain terms** ,so i click on the button **TermRecogniser** and i get the message error ! :(  How can i get the top domain terms on the home page?? there are in the json file but not on the page :(

Comment: If you're opening a local html file, the javascript context will not have access to make http requests to other endpoints. Check the developer console in your browser for any network errors if you're doing that and the Javascript attempts to make requests to get the terms.

Comment: This is what I get as a message in a Inspecter consol :`Failed to load http://localhost:8983/solr/jateCore/termRecogniser: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Which means what I was suggesting - if you're opening the HTML file directly, it isn't allowed to make any HTTP requests to the serve. Those files are probably meant to be served through the same web server that you're accessing Solr through. This is probably documented in the jate docs.

Comment: oky thanks , so i will try by url access `http://localhost:8983/solr/jateCore/termRecogniser `